# Magento2 - Refused to apply style

Tags: magento-2.1

Refused to apply style from `<URL>` because its `MIME` type (`text/html`) is not a supported `style sheet` `MIME` type, and strict `MIME` checking is enabled.

This is what I get when i try to load the page in Magento

Comment: please add the code how to added the stylesheet